# Testing Kotlin classes with Mockito causes MissingMethodInvocationException

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

So after alot of trail and error with a kotlin class i found that the same code in java is testable but not testable with kotlin.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestStuff {
    @Mock
    B b;

    @Test
    public void testStuff(){
        A a = new A(b);
        Mockito.when(b.provideValue()).thenReturn("");
        a.doStuff();
    }
}


class A(val b: B) {

    fun doStuff() {
        b.provideValue()
    }
}

open class B {
    fun provideValue(): String {
        return "b"
    }
}
```

This causes: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

But if i write class B as a java class i.e.

```
public class B {
    public String provideValue(){
        return "b";
    }
}
```

The test works.
Can some one explain why this is happening or how am i suposed to test kotlin code when mockito does not work consistently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mockito has problems with `final` classes or methods. As everything is `final` by default in Kotlin, you need to either write `open fun provideValue() : String` or use another mocking library or skip mocking at all ;-)

so your Java-class actually translated to Kotlin would look as follows (simplified):

```
open class B {
  open fun provideValue() = "b"
}
```

Just today I've heard of [mockk](http://mockk.io) and I tried your example. With that library you will not need to open up your classes and methods just for testing purposes, so you maybe want to take a look at it.

Comment: Oh my god. My mind is blown right now. I thought that making the class open will make it all of the functions work. Thank you mate will acept it as the correct answer as soon as the timer blocking runs out.

Comment: No problem. I updated the answer as [mockk](http://mockk.io) might be interesting for you.